# How much application pool size allowed for a social website?

Tags: asp.net

we have developed and deployed a Social portal [matrimonial service]. We have a dedicated server to run the site. Sql Server DB is used. We have store all information including customer images in to Database. For a test,When i see the app.pool size on task manager it consumes 300MB when i utilize all the page functions. I am only the online user showing as on google analytics.

my question is, i feel it takes more memory. But i dont know how much memory it will required for the social web application to run successfully for more than 200 online users.

please help me to know whether it is normal usage OR how to find memory leaks if any?

thanks in advance

Website: www.aranthangimatrimony.com

Developed using : ASP.net with VB as code behind

Comment: Without any hard data at all, it is impossible to estimate even for 10 users

Comment: Can i know what do u meant of hard data? it is ease for me to post necessary details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to do load tests on you application. This isn't a simple task but certainly doable with research. If you need to learn or do performance testing quickly I suggest you hire a consultant. Otherwise below are some resources.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924375.aspx
http://www.joecolantonio.com/2011/07/05/performance-testing-what-is-throughput/

There lots others. Google them.

In summary you will need as input the following, to simulate load on your system.
1. Number of concurrent and active users
2. List of user processes being performed on the system
3. A distribution of the processes in #2, i.e. How many users perform each process
4. Think times - time that simulates user reading a page or filling out a form or stops to think or decide what to do before interacting with a page

While you simulate load, you will have to measure response times and monitor resource utilization on your server.

Tools you can use
1. LoadRunner
2. Visual Studio
3. JMeter
4. Perfmon
5. Red Gate Ants profiler
6. CLRProfiler

Comment: thanks for valuable reply. surely i follow that. Can u suggest a best consultant? if you can help me please give your contact infomation.

Comment: Do you have a Geographical preference for your contractor?  Have you measured (in dollars) the cost of a failure to scale in lost customers, lost revenue, lost prestige?   How does this potential risk of loss match to your budget for performance engineering/testing services?

Comment: @user2935706 You can contact someone from HP or NeoLoad. They'll be more than happy to provide you information and perhaps a demo. But note, that this will cost you lot.